# Entering repeating data in Excel

Tags: excel

I am a travel agent and maintain a data base tracking my commission.   I am constantly adding new bookings which consist of a hotel name,  address and zip code.    Many of these hotels I use quite frequently so when i type the name of the hotel in cell  A1,   I wold like cell A2 to automatically populate  with the address,   cell A3 to populate with the state and cell A4 to populate with the zip.    I could eliminate a lot of data entry.  How could I do this.

Answer (score 1):

In another sheet enter the information for all the hotels. I suppose that you could have unique names for your hotels. You can use `VLOOKUP()` to search that table and populate that information.

If you want the information to appear automatically, just have more rows of formula than you have data on your sheet and use `IFERROR()` so that if there is no data entered into the first column you do not display an error.

As you can see here, the information is retrieved via `VLOOKUP` on another sheet and the formula you see is in `B2`. Normally that cell should display `#N/A` but since we are using `IFERROR()` this does not happen and you have a nice output.

[image]

And here because I think you might not be familiar with `VLOOKUP`. `VLOOKUP` has 4 parameters:

- The value to look for;
- The range in which 1) the value to look for is and 2) the value to retrieve is;
- The number of the column in which the information to retrieve is;
- 0 if you want an exact match, 1 if you want an approximate match

You just have to remember that `VLOOKUP` will *always* use the *first* column of the supplied range to search for the specified value so you 'key' has to be in the first column.

Answer (score 0):

Create an additional worksheet containing the hotel data and then use something like vlookup from your primary worksheet.